# How clear textfields when I submit form with Flutter?

Tags: php, flutter, dart

I started learning Flutter and Dart yesterday and I am making a registration form for an app for Android and iOs. Save the table to the DB perfectly, but I can't refresh the view or clear the textfields, and before a message with "success registration" or "error, the passwords are not equals", for example.

This is my register form:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'DashBoard.dart';
import 'main.dart';

class Register extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegisterState createState() => _RegisterState();
}

class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {
  TextEditingController correo = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController celular = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwd = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwd2 = TextEditingController();

  Future register() async {
    var url =
        "http://192.168.1.139/DataBase/register.php"; //IPv4, colocar después el hosting
    var response = await http.post(url, body: {
      "correo": correo.text,
      "celular": celular.text,
      "passwd": passwd.text,
      "passwd2": passwd2.text,
    });

    var data = json.decode(response.body);
    if (data == "Error") {
      FlutterToast(context).showToast(
          child: Text(
        'User allready exit!',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.red),
      ));
    } else {
      FlutterToast(context).showToast(
          child: Text('Registration Successful',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.green)));
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => DashBoard(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      // appBar: AppBar(
      //   // title: Text(
      //   //   '',
      //   //   style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      //   // ),
      // ),
      body: Container(
        height: 900,
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Register',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Correo',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  ),
                  controller: correo,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Celular',
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                    ),
                    controller: celular,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Contraseña',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  ),
                  controller: passwd,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Repita contraseña',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  ),
                  controller: passwd2,
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      color: Colors.pink,
                      child: Text('Regístrate',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        // correo.clear();
                        // celular.clear();
                        // passwd.clear();
                        // passwd2.clear();
                        register();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      color: Colors.amber[100],
                      child: Text('Login',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => MyHomePage(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is a example of Textfield and my submit button:

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: TextField(
     obscureText: true,
     decoration: InputDecoration(
     labelText: 'Contraseña',
       prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
       border: OutlineInputBorder(
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
     ),
     controller: passwd,
     ),
  ),
Row(
    children: <Widget>[
       Expanded(
         child: MaterialButton(
           color: Colors.pink,
           child: Text('Regístrate',
           style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.white)),
           onPressed: () {
           // correo.clear();
           // celular.clear();
           // passwd.clear();
           // passwd2.clear();
           register();
         },
      ),
),
```

Write passwd.clear() don't works for me. I'm new in this, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please help me, thanks

Comment: try using yourController.text = ""; and then a setState

Comment: Thanks, but don't work for me :(

Comment: Are you updating the view with setState((){}); ???

Comment: I was wrong where to put it, but now it works THANKS :D

Comment: Nice, please mark the comment as good answer please

Comment: I can't mark your comment as good answer cause only appears a redflag :( I'm sorry. Post an answer like the other guy with your correct answer and I will can mark that right now :) thanks for help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clear the content in a controller you have to options

1- Use clear option

```
yourController.clear();
```

2- Asign empty text to controler

```
yourController.text = "";
```

And independent which one you use, you have to add an setState after like this

```
setState((){});
```

Comment: Excelent answer, now it works THANKS :D !!!

Answer (score 0):

To clear the TextField or the TextFormField just use the clear() function like below :

```
TextEditingController textForm = TextEditingController();

 //clear the TextFormField
textForm.clear()
```

Comment: Thanks, but this don't work, I did exactly that, in my code it appears written, with the "clear()" and it doesn't work. :/